# nested LINQ query - list within list

Tags: c#, list, linq, nested

I have a special issue I want to solve by using LINQ but my solution does not work yet.
I condensed the structure to the minimum and hope it is easy to understand.
The classes are as follows:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> ListOfBs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<C> ListOfCs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I want to filter for specific C's and set them into a new List as property of a new instance of B (or even A). So I tried the following Linq query within a function:

```
    public B FilterFunction(A a, string someText)
    {
        B FilteredB = new B();
        FilteredB.ListOfCs = (from b in a.ListOfBs
                              from c in b.ListOfCs
                              where c.SomeText == someText
                              select c).ToList();
        return FilteredB;
    }
```

however, the returned list is empty, so I guess my LINQ query is not correct. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance
Martin

Comment: To be clear, you have an `A` that contains a `List<B>` and each `B` contains a `List<C>`, and you want to create and return a single new `B` that contains a `List<C>` where each `C` matches a specific condition? If so then that is a job for `SelectMany`. I'll put together an answer to that effect.

Comment: Your implementation is correct. Your problem should be on data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an object `a` of type `A`. This `a` has zero or more `Bs`, where every `B` has zero or more `Cs`. Every `C` has a String property `SomeText`.

You also have a String `someText`.

> I want to filter for specific C's and set them into a new List as property of a new instance of B.

This is a bit ambiguous. What do you want:

- I want all Cs with a value for Property `SomeText` that equals `someText`, that I can get via my `a` in one `B`. Literally your requirement says that you want one new Instance of B
- No, I want to create from Every `B` that I can get via `a`, one new `B`. This new `B` has all `Cs` that the original `B` had, with a value for Property `SomeText` that equals `someText`.

### Create one new instance of B

Whenever you have a sequence of items, where every item has a subsequence, and you want to regard these subsequences as one big sequence, consider to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0).

From all `Cs` that are in all `Bs` that are in your `a`, you want to make one new `B`. Well, not exactly all `Cs`, only those `Cs` that have the correct value for property `SomeText`.

```
A a = ...
string someText = ...

var oneNewB = new B
{
    ListOfCs = a.ListOfBs.SelectMany(b => b.ListOfCs)
        .Where(c => c.SomeText == someText)
        .ToList(),
};
```

In words: from a, get its list of Bs. From every B, use the subsequence `ListOfCs` to make one big sequence of Cs. Keep only those Cs that have a value for property SomeText that equals the value of someText. Use the remaining Cs to use as ListOfCs in one new B.

### Make one new B from every B in a

From every B in a.ListOfBs we make one new B. This new B contains only the Cs in the B that have a matching SomeText.

```
var newBs = a.ListOfBs.Select(b => new B
{
    ListOfCs = b.ListOfCs.Where(c => c.SomeText == someText).ToList(),
});
```

In words: From every B in a, make one new B. This new B contains only the Cs from the original B with the correct value for property SomeText.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may not be optimized but it works. Did you populate your lists  corectly?

```
B lb = new B();
lb.ListOfCs = new List<C>();
lb.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 1, SomeText = "1" });
lb.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 2, SomeText = "2" });
lb.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 3, SomeText = "3" });
       
B lb2 = new B();
lb2.ListOfCs = new List<C>();
lb2.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 10, SomeText = "10" });
lb2.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 20, SomeText = "20" });
lb2.ListOfCs.Add(new C { ID = 30, SomeText = "10" });

A la = new A();
la.ListOfBs = new List<B>();
la.ListOfBs.Add(lb2);
la.ListOfBs.Add(lb);

FilterFunction(la, "10").ListOfCs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ID));
```

Result 10, 30

Answer (score 1):

You may use `.SelectMany()` to flatten `ListOfCs` for easing the query of the C element.

[.SelectMany()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
public B FilterFunction(A a, string someText)
{
    B FilteredB = new B();
    FilteredB.ListOfCs = a.ListOfBs
        .SelectMany(b => b.ListOfCs)
        .Where(c => c.SomeText == someText)
        .ToList();
    
    return FilteredB;
}
```

[Sample code & test data](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i5OPEX)

Answer (score 1):

Using `SelectMany` as suggested:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new A
                {
                    ListOfBs = new List<B>
                               {
                                   new B
                                   {
                                       ListOfCs = new List<C>
                                                  {
                                                      new C {ID = 1, SomeText = "One"},
                                                      new C {ID = 2, SomeText = "Two"}
                                                  }
                                   },
                                   new B
                                   {
                                       ListOfCs = new List<C>
                                                  {
                                                      new C {ID = 3, SomeText = "Three"},
                                                      new C {ID = 4, SomeText = "Four"}
                                                  }
                                   }
                               }
                };

        var b = FilterFunction(a, "T");

        foreach (var c in b.ListOfCs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{c.ID}: {c.SomeText}");
        }
    }

    public static B FilterFunction(A a, string someText)
    {
        return new B
               {
                   ListOfCs = a.ListOfBs
                               .SelectMany(b => b.ListOfCs.Where(c => c.SomeText.StartsWith(someText)))
                               .ToList()
               };
    }
}

public class A
{
    public List<B> ListOfBs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<C> ListOfCs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I forgot how much quicker C# questions get answered compared to VB.NET questions.

Answer (score 0):

With `.SelectMany` you can flatten all `C` lists into one and filter it

```
public B FilterFunction(A a, string someText)
{
    return new B
    {
        ListOfCs = a.ListOfBs
            .SelectMany(bc => bc.ListOfCs)
            .Where(c => c.SomeText == someText)
            .ToList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public B FilterFunction(A a, string someText)
{
    B FilteredB = new B();
    FilteredB.ListOfCs = a.ListOfCs.Where(c=> c.SomeText.Equals(someText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
    return FilteredB;
}
```

Comment: A doesn't has a ListOfC Property

Comment: Oops, I did not see that, check @Fabio's answer